# Why is one of (array) field/value pairs in MongoDB's find_and_modify() filter parameter being ignored?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb

I am using pymongo to call MongoDB 3.2 (running on Azure Cosmos DB). My app needs to, in an atomic step, search for an array element in a document and if found, modify 1-2 of its fields.

For the filter argument, I am specifying 3 conditions (see **fd** in code).  The first call seems to work OK (it modifies the first element in the array which happens to match **fd**), but on the second call, it modifies the second array element that doesn't match the **node_id** value specified in the filter.  My code:

```
fd = {'_id': 'job7569', 'active_runs.node_id': 'node0', 'active_runs.status': 'unstarted'}
ud = {'active_runs.$.run_name': 'run8100.1', 'active_runs.$.status': 'started'}

result = self.mongo.mongo_db["__jobs__"].find_and_modify(fd, update={"$set": ud}, fields={"active_runs.$": 1}, new=True)
```

**active_runs** after 2nd call:

```
[   {'node_id': 'node0', 'run_index': 0, 'run_name': 'run9999.43', 'status': 'started'}, 
    {'node_id': 'node1', 'run_index': 1, 'run_name': 'run9999.44', 'status': 'started'}, 
    {'node_id': 'node2', 'run_index': 2, 'run_name': None, 'status': 'unstarted'}, 
    ...]
```

Comment: Because you have 2 uncorrelated queries against `active_runs`.  Try doing that with `$elemMatch`.

Comment: That fixed it - thanks!

Comment: @RolandFernandez Would you please summarize your solution as an answer for others' reference. Thanks a lot.